# How to create a tally counter in Python with UI integration?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Say I'm watching a game show, and want to keep track of how often they say 3 words. The words are "winner", "loser" and "game". I want to set up a Python file where I can assign certain keys of my keyboard to increment the count of a dictionary, keeping track of the respective frequencies of the 3 words.

For example,

Let's set the "w" key on my keyboard to winner, the 'l' key to loser, and the 'g' key to game.

I can set up a simple dictionary:

```
tracker = {'winner':0,'loser':0,'game':0}
```

Now, as I'm watching the show, I want to set something up so that every time I hit the "w" key, the tracker dictionary value for 'winner' is incremented by 1, and so on and so forth.

Unfortunately I don't know much about UI integration at all. Is there an easy way to set this up?

Thanks so much and have a wonderful day.

Comment: do you even need a GUI? at least at first try to recreate the same thing in command line UI (I could also suggest `keyboard` module then), otherwise you need to show what you have tried and provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

##### Can I introduce you to streamlit.io? This creates an app out of your python code.

```
pip install streamlit
```

Then open up your terminal and change the directory to your Desktop. Create a python file with.

```
touch counter_app.py
```

Drag and drop this file into visual studio code. Now paste this code into the file:

```
import streamlit as st

st.title('Counting App for AL92')
st.write(' ')
st.write(' ')


  
if 'count' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.count = 0

increment = st.button('winner')
if increment:
    st.session_state.count += 1

st.write('Count = ', st.session_state.count)





if 'count2' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.count2 = 0

increment2 = st.button('looser')
if increment2:
    st.session_state.count2 += 1

st.write('Count2 = ', st.session_state.count2)





if 'count3' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.count3 = 0

increment3 = st.button('game')
if increment3:
    st.session_state.count3 += 1

st.write('Count3 = ', st.session_state.count3)
```

Open up the terminal and within the Desktop directory type in:

```
streamlit run counter_app.py
```

You will get following app:

[image]

This app will open up automatically within your browser locally. I know, these are not keyboard presses but you will have an app that saves the counting states of each button.

If you closed the tab you can simply re-run the app locally with streamlit run counter_app.py. You can also publish this simple app with its own URL on streamlit.io.

Comment: I am pretty sure about two things: OP asked for a counter that can be increased via a key press and that `tkinter` is tagged (not that it would matter since OP didn't ask about any library specifically, but that also is an issue: the question lacks focus)